# undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass error while unzipping using archive-zip in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using archive-zip gem for unzipping zip files inside ruby code to be used in a scheduler task.
Some times it is working fine but few times i am getting "undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass" error while unzipping in Archive:zip line.

The code snippet is

```
require 'archive/zip'

Dir.foreach("#{Rails.public_path}/#{zip_folder}/") do |item|

Archive::Zip.extract("#{Rails.public_path}/#{zip_folder}/"+ item, "#{Rails.public_path}/#{zip_folder}/inspected/", :password => 'password')

end
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which ruby version what system ? What zip libraries you have system level installed ? Show us what your'e getting via http://ascii.io/

Comment: I am using ruby 1.8.7 with archive-zip (0.5.0) for unzipping.I am facing this same issue in both Windows 7 and Fedora release 14 (Laughlin) system.

Comment: You don't posted a asciio or pastie output from your console.

Comment: It is the only output i get in console.                                                                                                                                 "rake aborted!
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the zip file using another Java library for zipping which was not compatible with Ruby Unzip library. So created another API to unzip using the same Java library.